# count records and email

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath

I'm working on a SharePoint list to record sick days. So I've got a form to fill out the basic information, but I want to automatically count how many sickdays there has been in the past year, then when there are at least 4, to email the manager.

I've got the basic part of the list built, names, dates, I've got the manager lookup working, but I'm having issues with the count, then the email. I'll admit to being a SharePoint novice.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show me the list structure?

Comment: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_JP5_YM4ogBWVg2REJQUUtiT1k/view?usp=sharing)    Let me know if you need something else.

Comment: Anyone? I really need help with this.

Thanks.